# Swift: Invalid Type in JSON write(UIImage)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, nsdata, nsurlsession

I am trying to convert `UIImage` to `base 64` string so that it can be saved to a file and then uploaded. I am doing the following:

**Code Snippet :**

```
var writePath: String!
var params: NSMutableDictionary = ["file1": UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image!, 1.0)!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)), "userId" : user_id]

    do {
        let bodyJson = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .PrettyPrinted)
        let path: NSURL = NSURL(string: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0])!
        writePath = path.URLByAppendingPathComponent("body.data").absoluteString
        try bodyJson.writeToFile(writePath, options: .AtomicWrite)
        writePath = String(format: "file://%@", writePath)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

But, I am getting the Invalid Type error. I have to use background session and also need to send some parameters, so, I am using this method.

[image]

SOLVED: Some other thing was causing this problem.

Comment: Can you add the error screenshot? is user_id an Int?

Comment: @MarcoSantarossa user_id is String. I have other parameters too. They all are Strings.

Comment: you can write `var params: [String: String]`. Anyway, can you add the error screenshot?

Comment: @MarcoSantarossaI have added the screenshot.

Comment: That's strange indeed. Could you check that `params["file"]` is a string?

Comment: @Larme Yes, it is string. I printed out the params dictionary. In that, file1 shows as "<UIImage: 0x7fa52b211220> size {501, 750} orientation 0 scale 1.000000". No idea why.

Comment: It seems that `params["file"]` is a `UIImage`. Could you try to do it piece by piece. `let imageRepresentationData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(...); let base64ImageStr = imageRepresentationData. base64EncodedStringWithOptions(...)` and put that into `params`?

Comment: @Larme I have tried doing this step by step, but same result.

Comment: And the class of the intermediates objects are correct? `NSData` then `NSString`?

Comment: @Larme Yes, they are same. However, it is String instead of NSString.

Comment: @Larme If I print out file1 outside params dictionary, it prints out the complete image as it should do, but when i print out the complete params dictionary, it prints out  "<UIImage: 0x7fa52b211220> size {501, 750} orientation 0 scale 1.000000"

Comment: @Larme Thanks, I double checked dictionary variable, made some changes and now, it is working

Answer (score 1):

*Just an attempt to solve*, try this:

```
    var writePath: String!
    let params: [String: String] = ["file1": UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView1.image!, 1.0)!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength), "userId" : user_id]

    do {
        let bodyJson = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: .PrettyPrinted)
        let path: NSURL = NSURL(string: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0])!
        writePath = path.URLByAppendingPathComponent("body.data").absoluteString
        try bodyJson.writeToFile(writePath, options: .AtomicWrite)
        writePath = String(format: "file://%@", writePath)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference b/w my code and yours? Looks same.

Comment: @KaranveerSingh I added a swift dictionary and `Encoding64CharacterLineLength`option. I have no problem with this code

Comment: I have already tried this option but had same problem. I have saved this image in Core Data. Could that be a problem?

Comment: If I print out file1 outside params dictionary, it prints out the complete image as it should do, but when i print out the complete params dictionary, it prints out "<UIImage: 0x7fa52b211220> size {501, 750} orientation 0 scale 1.000000"

Comment: Thanks, I double checked dictionary variable, made some changes and now, it is working

Comment: @KaranveerSingh nice! If my answer helped please upvote or mark as right. thanks

Comment: Hi, Sorry to bother you after so long. Do you know if it is possible to upload the file without saving in documents directory. Because app is core data based. So, basically I dont want to save the same entry in core data and then as file in documents.

Comment: @KaranveerSingh you can store your data in a `NSData` object

Comment: I am using background session and it doesnt upload nsdata , it only uploads files.

Answer (score 0):

We are doing the following (excuse the obj-c to swift conversion that could be slightly wrong):

```
let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img,0.5)
let base64Encoded = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(0)
let jsonDic = ["image" : base64Encoded]
...
...
```

And now `jsonDic` can be converted to proper serialized JSON using `NSJSONSerialization`.

**Also very important to make sure that your jsonDic keys are always strings. You can not create a proper JSON serialized object if the key is not a string.**

Comment: Thanks, I double checked dictionary variable, made some changes and now, it is working